# how to enter the data only if all instructions are correct in my migration files?

Tags: database, flyway

Hello I use flyway for versioning my database however i'm starting now and i'm with a doubt. If i have two files with sqls instructions and the first file all sqls instructions are correct but in the second there is an error and if i do migrate with the flyway the first file 's instructions will be included in my database , however i wanted it to be inserted so that all instructions of the two files were correct someone already go through something like that?

my code is below.

```
        flyway.setDataSource(con,user,pass);
    flyway.setSchemas("database");

    //Repara o banco para inserir as novas migrações
    flyway.repair();

    //Insere as migrações no banco de dados
    flyway.migrate();
```

V1_file.sql

```
CREATE TABLE flyway (
    name VARCHAR(100)
    );
```

V2_file.sql

```
alter table flyway add x int

alter table flyway add y int
```

v3_file.sql

```
CREATE TABLE flyway (
    name VARCHAR(100)
    );
```

the flyway table already exists if it happened a similar situation so as to enter the data every sql files did not have any errors
Is very simple but i really need this.

sorry my english is terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flyway runs each migration inside a transaction. If you want statements to be committed or rolled back together, you have to place them within the same .sql file.

Comment: I understand then the programmer must ensure the sql file that will be right.